# How can I force my node express js app to view my 500 error

Tags: node.js, express

I want to be able to force my 500 error to show so I can see if I have set it up correctly. How can I go about doing this?

This is what I have.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {res.status(500); res.redirect('/redirects/500.html'); });
```

Comment: I guess that you have to do things in your client, like use interceptors to catch http errors.

Comment: @YerkoPalma Thank you for your comment. I came across "generate an error by calling an undefined function in one of your route handlers." googling this. Does this make any sense to you?